# Obtain centroid of a queryset of points (PointField) with Django

Tags: python, django, geodjango, centroid

I would need to obtain the centroid of a queryset of points (PointField) with Django

Here are my models:

```
class GroupOfCities(models.Model)
    geomcentroid = models.PointField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=True)

class City(models.Model):
    centroid = models.PointField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=True)
    groupofcities = models.ForeignKey(GroupOfCities, null=True)
```

I would need to get the centroid of each group of cities and save it to geomcentroid

Example of what I would like to do for one group of cities:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Centroid

firstgroupofcities = GroupeOfCities.objects.get(id=1)
cities = City.objects.filter(groupofcities=firstgroupofcities).annotate(cent=Centroid('centroid'))
firstgroupofcities.geomcentroid = cities.cent
firstgroupofcities.save()
```

But this "Centroid" functionality only works for polygons.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over the queryset and calculate the centroid in Python -- the code below is untested, but the approach should work.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

firstgroupofcities = GroupeOfCities.objects.get(id=1)
cities = City.objects.filter(groupofcities=firstgroupofcities)
x_average = 0
y_average = 0

for idx, city in enumerate(cities):
    x_average = x_average*(idx/(idx+1)) + city.centroid.coords[0]/(idx+1)
    y_average = y_average*(idx/(idx+1)) + city.centroid.coords[1]/(idx+1)

cent = Point(x_average, y_average)

firstgroupofcities.geomcentroid = cent
firstgroupofcities.save()
```

Additionally, you'll probably want to either:

1) run the calculation each time the fkey relationship on `City` is changed by overriding `save()` or using [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/)

OR

2) calculate it each time you need the data by putting it in a method of `GroupOfCities`

Lastly, if none of that works and you're using Postgres and you're required to do the calculation in the DB, you might have an alternative using these:

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePolygon.html

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Union` aggregate function:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.aggregates import Union
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Centroid

for goc in GroupOfCities.objects.annotate(cent=Centroid(Union('city_set__centroid')):
    goc.geomcentroid = goc.cent
    goc.save()
```

(It basically creates the "polygon" needed by "Centroid".)